# Accessing App.config

Tags: c#, configuration, connection-string, app-config

I have the following in my App.config, how do I make the code below it work????

```
configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="WpfDatabind3.Properties.Settings.cbfSQL1ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=STEPHANS-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=cbfSQL1;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

I can't figure out how to access the connection string in the App.config.

```
DataSet myDataSet;

private void OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string mdbFile = Path.Combine(AppDataPath, "BookData.mdb");
  string connString = string.Format(
      "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}", mdbFile);
  OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
  OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM BookTable;", conn);

  myDataSet = new DataSet();
  adapter.Fill(myDataSet, "BookTable");

  // myListBox is a ListBox control. 
  // Set the DataContext of the ListBox to myDataSet
  myListBox.DataContext = myDataSet;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add reference to `System.Configuration.dll` to your project. Then use [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class. It allows to get connection string settings by name:

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager
   .ConnectionStrings["WpfDatabind3.Properties.Settings.cbfSQL1ConnectionString"]
   .ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Nope, The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Then you are missing the reference

Comment: Yea, I was, I know I put it in, but when i rechecked it was not there.  now I have to get myDataSet' in context